# Search particular restaurant according to food

Tags: laravel

I have a search input where users are supposed to searchso as to return results

```
<div class="field" id="searchform">

        <input type="text" id="searchterm" placeholder="e.g mutton 

        karahi,pizza..."  />

        <button type="button" id="search" 

        onclick="window.location='http://localhost:8000/search'">Find Food!</button>

        </div>
```

The food items are in a table called foods which has the following fields

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->string('food_item')
            $table->integer('restaurant_id');
        });
```

The is a different table for restaurants where the foods table gets restaurant_id

How can go about this

Comment: Will you make relationship between `restaurant` table and `food` table ? I think this relationship is `Many to Many`. [Check document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: i have made the relationship its actually one to many because a particular restaurant has many food items but a food item with a particular id belongs to a restaurant

Comment: No problem with your relationship, it's up to you. So you can get the restaurant name by using relationship like this: `$food->pluck('restaurant')->flatten();` with `restaurant` is your relationship name.